# How to Total amounts looping through ServiceBus Queue in Azure logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a Azure Logic app that will pull all messages of a queue once a day. In the Loop action, I can extract the amount and convert to float to extract the value, however, I am not sure how to create a running total of all of the messages in the queue. To be clear, so if there are 10 messages in the queue, and each message has an amount of $1, the running total at the end should be $10. Does anyone know how to do this ?

I have tried using the Math function add(variables('TotalPayments'), variables('PaymentAmount'))
TotalPayments  - Running Total
PaymentAmount - current Payment extracted from the current Message.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to this, What I used was to implement a increment variable and assigned the value from the current message to this variable. There could be an easier way of doing this, however, It achieves the desired result, and I spent far too much time on it. Microsoft may have meant some other way, but isn't forthcoming in the documentation (that I could find, would be gladly told otherwise). Like I indicated above, I was using the Math function add which seemed logical to me to use but that didn't work.